# Do NVME SSDs exist in 2230 form-factor?

Tags: ssd, nvme

I have just got Dell 3530 laptop, and they advertise an option to install second hard drive in WWAN slot. However, it has to be NVME (no SATA!) and it has to be 2230.

I have looked a lot, but the only NVME SSD in 2230 I was able to find was Toshiba BG3, but this one I can't find on sale anywhere. Do those exist beyond this elusive model, of "which everyone talks about and few have seen"  (Quote from Francois de La Rochefoucauld)

Comment: @Ramhound how would I search for those? The query verbatim gives me nothing: https://www.google.com/search?q=M.2+256GB+PCIe+NVMe+Class+35+SSD&oq=M.2+256GB+PCIe+NVMe+Class+35+SSD&aqs=chrome..69i64j5.3179j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The Toshiba BG3 is an OEM only part.  You won’t be able to find it

Comment: @Ramhound none of those are 2230 PCIe.

Comment: Not every day you read a de La Rochefoucauld-ism

Comment: @bertieb it's a good quote, and applicable in many cases :)

Comment: @Ramhound if know a specific model, can you please share it's number as an answer and I will more than happy to accept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Hardware Recommendations https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here they sell it.

I am in the same situation, sooner or later I will try...

https://www.centralpoint.nl/solid-state-drives/toshiba/512gb-m-2-2230-s3-ssm-client-ssd-art-kbg30zms512ga-num-8110137/

Comment: I do not speak Dutch, and I can't even tell if they ship to US. But nevertheless, good catch! Thanks.

Comment: Also dutch but. https://tweakers.net/pricewatch, select Solid state drives, select M2 30mm. -> two hits. WD SN520 M.2 30mm and Toshiba BG3 Series M.2 2230. Supplied by 1) central point. 1) Redable.  2) Aces zakelijk. 4) Beat-it.nl.    So rare but findable, and now you have two types to google on.